# Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 - error in network definition when trying to set static IP with sudo netplan apply

Tags: 18.04, netplan, static-ip

I get this error when trying to set static IP with the command sudo netplan apply:
Error in network definition //etc/netplan/50-cloud.init.yaml line 5 column 34: expected scalar

Here's what my config file looks like:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp5s0:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [192.168.85.17/24]
            gateway4: [192.168.85.19]
            nameservers: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
            optional: true
version: 2
```

Comment: Hi, please be more precise on how you tried to do this, and perhaps don't throw some picture at us, but edit your question, to hold the information in text, both makes it easier to help you

Answer (score 1):

gateway4 takes an address, not a list of addresses. So the syntax should be:
        gateway4: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: I'm sorry, that was improper formatting/indenting on my post. The actual file is properly indented I believe. I edited my post to show what it actually looks like.